# How to find key pattern in multiline text using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, stored-procedures

I'm using regular expression to parse  stored procedures in order to modify them.
here is my sample text:

```sql
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    TempID          int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    AMFID           smallint,
    AppModID        smallint,
    AppID           tinyint,
    ModID           smallint,
    FPID            smallint,
    URL         varchar(100),
    SortIndex       smallint,
    [AppName]       varchar(100),
    ModName     varchar(100),
    FPName      varchar(100),
    WUCData     varchar(7000)
)

-- Fill the temp table
INSERT INTO @TempTable
(
    AMFID,
    AppModID,
    AppID,
    ModID,
    FPID,
    URL,
    SortIndex,
    [AppName],
    ModName,
    FPName,
    WUCData
)
SELECT
    siAppModFP.AMFID,
    siAppModFP.AppModID,
    siAppModule.AppID,
    siAppModule.ModID,
    siAppModFP.FPID,
    siAppModFP.URL,
    siAppModFP.SortIndex,
    siApplication.[AppName],
    siModule.ModName,
    siFP.FPName,
    dbo.funcGetAppModFPWUC(siAppModFP.AMFID)
FROM siApplication WITH (NOLOCK)
```

...

I just want to get this part:

```sql
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    TempID          int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    AMFID           smallint,
    AppModID        smallint,
    AppID           tinyint,
    ModID           smallint,
    FPID            smallint,
    URL         varchar(100),
    SortIndex       smallint,
    [AppName]       varchar(100),
    ModName     varchar(100),
    FPName      varchar(100),
    WUCData     varchar(7000)
)
```

Notice it might be repeated more than once.  I want all declarations of temp tables in the text.
I used following regular pattern:

```
string re1 = "(Declare)( )(@)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))(\\s+)(Table)(\\s+)(\\(.*\\))";
Regex r = new Regex(re1, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it's not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: This tool is great for testing specific text with specific patterns.  You can examine individual capture groups, and the right side bar is a regex cheatsheet. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: you are using multiline mode instead of singleline mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `singleline` mode **not** `multiline` mode

Use this `regex` with `singleline` mode

```
declare\s*@(?:[a-z]\w*)\s*table.*?\)\s*\)
```

So,it should be

```
string re1 = @"declare\s*@(?:[a-z]\w*)\s*table.*?\)\s*\)";
Regex r = new Regex(re1 ,RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: Thank you... working now, great idea to consider two )) instead of rounding parantheses

Comment: @user1778790 i didnt get u..if u r asking how to replace `?` itself u can replace it by escaping it like this: `\?`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Regex`:

```
DECLARE\s+@(\w+)\s+TABLE\s+\(([^,\(\)]+(\(\d+\))?(,)?)+\)
```

and a sample code:

```
var pattern = @"DECLARE\s+@(\w+)\s+TABLE\s+\(([^,\(\)]+(\(\d+\))?(,)?)+\)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, pattern);

foreach(Match match in matches)
    Output.Lines.Add(match.ToString());

// or in LINQ way
var result = from Match match in matches select match.ToString();
```

Comment: This will not work as brackets can open and close multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get [balancing brackets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"declare\s\@([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\w+table\w*\(((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+\)");
```